# What is continuous integration?

Tags: version-control, configuration, continuous-integration

What is continuous integration and what are its benefits?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[This](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) is by far the best explanation I have read so far.

Comment: Fowler almost always has the best explanations =)

Comment: I am simply amazed by the way he thinks about things ! CLEAR

Comment: No need write on other's words are great

Answer (score 9):

At its simplest, it is simply a mechanism that rebuilds your project whenever a check in is made into some revision control system (CVS etc). This can be extended though to include running tests, all the way through to generating a CD image, mounting it within VMs, installing the product and running full tests on it.

It has the simple advantage of highlighting when code changes break the system as early as possible. Not only does it detect breaks in the code, it highlights who caused the break. This psychological effect is very effective in encouraging good testing prior to check in!

Answer (score 5):

It is the practice of ensuring that all aspects of your software development process are lined up to permit the daily creation of a working version of your product.  It is best known as part of Extreme Programming.

This involves things as far afield as build automation, automated testing, daily check-ins, using a source code repository, etc.  But the ultimate goal is to help the entire project run according to core Agile Principles so that you deliver early and often.  This, in turn, helps you leverage feedback from your users, etc.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for the link to Fowler's page.

Personally, I just found it "nice" to know whenever something didn't compile because we had the poor practice of having a single build (yes, we developed on the production build; we were awesome).  We hadn't got the integrated testing phase before I left.

After a while, it did, however, lessen the amount of massive coding changes (compared to the "check in and pray my changes don't conflict" that was rampant).  Eventually, most developers started making small changes frequently just to get confirmation from the CC.Net tray icon.

Overall, I found it very comforting to know that we could send out a build immediately if we had to.  Had we had just a few smoke tests integrated, I think the stress-level would have been substantially lower.

Comment: I just like the last sentence! It is a gold!

Answer (score -2):

Just to refresh. At this point there is a huge difference between Continuous Integration (CI) and Continuous Delivery (CD). While most of posts above described CD I'll try to show how CI extends now CD definition. Having all the tools needed to build a package and deploy new version of app automatically is a crucial part of CD. Adding to that test automation (based on three level verification: General Health-check, Detailed Statistics and Historical entries) and a proper governance you're creating a really good piece of CI. Only because of such an extended definition building extraordinary cloud tools is possible. Think about muleESB or esbeetle.com. For both of them CI is something natural although only the second one is supporting both ESB and ETL components.

I hope that it was helpful.